# Type or namespace name could not be found...

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with many projects. All are reusable class libraries except one that is a console application I am using to build test cases. I can successfully reference some projects, but not others. I can add a reference to the projects, but when I reference them with a using statement, some of the project references fail at compile time with a "type or namespace name 'project name' could not be found.

The strange thing about this is that I am successfully referencing all of these projects in another separate application, but within this solution, I can reference some successfully and not others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Visual Studio 2010 creates Console apps against the .Net Framework Client Profile. Often times this is incompatible with existing libraries built against the full framework. Go to you console app, go to properties, and change the target framework to .Net Framework 4.

Comment: And, of course, you DON'T want to choose .Net 4.0 for ANY MSVS2010 project unless you NEED .Net 4.0 features.  It's always best to override the default, and choose the LOWEST version of .Net you can...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has caught us in past versions of visual studio (but may no longer be applicable) is when we tried to reference projects with the same GUID.

I haven't tested this recently, but you might check to see whether or not projects in your current solution have identifiers that are the same as those in the newly referenced projects.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion: maybe you just need to add some additional references in the MSVS IDE...